# Weird shape drawing position

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using the Drawing Manager, and if the map place in the top/left position of the screen works perfectly, but when the map is in other position, the Drawing Manager draws the line but has a weird behaviour, the "next position point" is not centered where the mouse pointer is.

See the picture:

[image]

```js
var lat = 40.4167754;
var lng = -3.7037901;
var mapOptions, map, maker, drawingManager;

function initialize() {

    mapOptions = {
        center: { lat: lat, lng: lng },
        zoom: 13
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    maker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: lat, lng: lng },
        map: map
    });

    drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE
            ]
        },
        circleOptions: {
            fillColor: '#ffff00',
            fillOpacity: 1,
            strokeWeight: 5,
            clickable: false,
            editable: true,
            zIndex: 1
        }
    });

    drawingManager.setMap(map);

}

function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp' +
        '&libraries=geometry,visualization,drawing&signed_in=true&callback=initialize&key=XXX';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    loadScript();
});
```

Comment: Question is unclear. I see nothing wrong in the picture or in your code. Works for me with 3.exp. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: The mouse pointer is on the right but the line points to the right. Nothing matter, changing the version works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the js version. The version 3 works perfectly, not the 3.exp

```js
script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3' +
        '&libraries=geometry,visualization,drawing&signed_in=true&callback=initialize&key=XXX';
```

Comment: Probably would be helpful if you could file a bug report in the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20API%20v3%20-%20Bug), eventually the experimental version becomes the release version... (unless this was only in Firefox, in which case it may be a duplicate)

Comment: For me, it is using Firefox